# axis values doesnt display in figure while working in octave

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave

Hi I am using GNU Octave, version 3.2.4.

While using plot or stem axis values are not shown in the figure window.

I am using GNUPLOT Version 4.4. When I plot something separately in gnuplot, it gives no error. For example in gnuplot:

```
set  xrange [1:100];plot(x);
```

The above shows a plot with values on both axes, but the same isn't working in octave:

```
x=[1:100];plot(x);
```

This results on a figure window without any axis values.

I have tried all axis property options available in octave. Auto scaling works but values are still not displaying. Can anyone suggests how to correct this issue?

Comment: Please update to a newer version, 3.2.4 is too old. We're at 3.8.

Comment: @juliohm Talking of Octave 3.8, do you know when the Windows release will be available?

Comment: @am304, try [this link](http://octave.osuv.de/3.8/windows/)

Comment: @juliohm Thanks I had seen it, but is this "work in progress"? My understanding is that this isn't the final/official build..

Comment: @am304, software is always work in progress. ;]

Comment: @juliohm Indeed :-) What I meant was that there is no reference to Octave 3.8 on http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Windows or http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/

Comment: @juliohm thank you. I am working in a lab. All systems have fedora. i did not get any link for installing octave 3.8 for fedora. so i have installed 3.2.4. and the problem i am facing is only in one pc. rest of the systems are working fine.can you plz suggest me any link to install octave 3.8 for fedora?..

Comment: @user3217762, you have to check with your distribution on what version is available, see [here](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/octave?_csrf_token=f703aa4d38b9bf1b54db74925e7720218a429897). In any case, also check if your `~/.octaverc` is doing something on your behalf.

Comment: @juliohm thank you. It worked fine with octave 3.8.0.